# Do US taxi rates depend on day/night or weekday/weekend?

Tags: usa, taxis, price, rates

In Norway, taxi rates are often higher during the night or weekend compared to weekday office hours.  Is this true for the United States?  I can't find anything about it on [taxifarefinder](http://www.taxifarefinder.com).

Comment: Taxi ? You mean cab. Lemme chime in with them Alabama taxis. In Birmingham, its $2 a mile. That is, of course, if you ever manage to get a cab!

Answer (score 4):

Typically, yes, although it undoubtedly depends on where in the US you are. For example, in New York City, [there are night-time and peak-hour weekday surcharges](http://www.nyc.gov/html/tlc/html/passenger/taxicab_rate.shtml) of $0.50 and $1 respectively.